# Does the Zeta Distribution converge to normal as N gets large

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem, zeta-functions

I am curious if the zeta distribution converges to normal if it is summed over many times. I am particularly curious if this is true for $\zeta$(4). I know that, if it does converge to normal, it would have to be for $\zeta \ge 4$ because the distribution would not have a finite variance otherwise. If I understand the Central Limit Theorem correctly, this distribution would converge if it is IID and has a finite variance. I have tried using the following definition for the CLT to show convergence, but am running into issues.
$\lim_{n_\to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) = \Phi (x)$

Where $ S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$ and $\phi (x)$ is the standard normal distribution

and $X_i$ is the zeta distribution.

Since $X_i$ is $\frac{1}{\zeta(4) k^4}$, then $ S_n$ is $\frac{n}{\zeta(4) k^4}$

So, $\lim_{n_\to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{S_n}{n} - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) = \Phi (x)$

Reduces down to $\lim_{n_\to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{n}{n\zeta(4) k^4} - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) = \Phi (x)$

= $\lim_{n_\to \infty} P(\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{1}{\zeta(4) k^4} - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) = \Phi (x)$

This diverges as n goes toward infinity. I am uncertain as to what I have done wrong here. Have I made a mistake or does this imply that the zeta distribution does not converge to Normal?

If anyone has some insight into this problem, please let me know.

Comment: What issues exactly are you running into?

Comment: Mainly, when I plug in $S_n$ and $\mu$ and $\sigma$, and I try to take the limit, I am not getting an answer that is convergent. The answer is diverging as N goes to infinity.

Comment: Could you edit your post to provide more detail? The CLT should work for i.i.d. $\zeta(s)$ variables as soon as $s>3$.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the definition of a zeta distribution. It is not $X_i = \frac{1}{\zeta(4) k^4}$; rather it is $P(X_i = k) = \frac{1}{\zeta(4) k^4}$. This does not imply $P(S_n = k) = \frac{n}{\zeta(4) k^4}$.

Answer (score 1):

The CLT is usually stated as $P(\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{1}{n} S_n - \mu}{\sigma} \le x) \to \Phi(x)$. (Note that the right-hand side is the CDF $\Phi$, not the PDF $\phi$ of the standard normal distribution.) The quantity $\sqrt{n}\frac{\frac{1}{n} S_n - \mu}{\sigma}$ can be rewritten as $\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}}$, but is not equal to $\frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ as you have written.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my errors @angryavian. I have corrected them, but still am running into issues. If you could look at my updated work and let me know what you think, that would be much appreciated.